# Hide specific Childen in ExpandableListView

Tags: hide, expandablelistview, children

I have 3 kinds of children in my `expandableListview`.
For simplicity I want to let the user choose which one is visible and which is not.

```
    public void setMenuItem(MenuItem item){

    if(item.isChecked())
          item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.type0:
            if(item.isChecked())adapter.type0=View.VISIBLE;
            else adapter.type0=View.GONE; break;
        case R.id.type1:
            if(item.isChecked())adapter.type1=View.VISIBLE;
            else adapter.type1=View.GONE; break;
        case R.id.type2:
            if(item.isChecked())adapter.type2=View.VISIBLE;
            else adapter.type2=View.GONE;
            break;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

The `getView` in the expandable List custom adapter looks like this:

```
  @Override
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean 
  isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

  ArrayList<Exercises> child = (ArrayList<Exercises>)childtems
         .get(groupPosition);   
  if (view == null) {   
      LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)context
       .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandchild, null);
  }

  TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandChildText);
  tv.setText(child.get(childPosition).toString());

         switch(child.get(childPosition).type){
            case 0 : view.setVisibility(type0);break;
            case 1 : view.setVisibility(type1);break;
            case 2 : view.setVisibility(type2);break;
         }  
  return view;

 }
```

What happens is, expandable List view shows still all children, whether visibility is set to .gone or not!

If it's gone, it just shows an **empty** child, without any textview etc, but I want to hide the child completely!

What's the trick there?
One Solution would be to remove specific data from adapter of course, but I think it would be like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut...

Comment: Thanks for the edits, sorry i am not a native speaker :)

Comment: Solved it.

When checkboxei is (un)checked i create a filtered copy of Adapter Data and create a new Adapter.

But like i said in Questions, it seems like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut... hoped there would be a nicer way.